# Evaluate java expression using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am getting hard time in evaluating java expression using groovy.
Below is my code where I have to dynamically push replace statements and evaluate it. replaceSpecialChars value comes from user input.

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");
```

```java
String text =  "Disa";
System.out.println(text); //1
text = text.replace("s", "");
System.out.println(text); //2
String removeSpecialChars =  ".replace('a','')";
text = text + removeSpecialChars;
System.out.println(text); //3
engine.put("first", text);
System.out.println(engine.eval("first")); //4
```

4 Sysout Outputs -

```
Disa 
Dia 
Dia.replace('a','')
Dia.replace('a','')
```

Expected Outputs -

```
Disa
Dia
Dia.replace('a','')
Di
```

Comment: My gut reaction is that this is an X-Y problem. What’s the ultimate goal here?

Comment: Goal is to get user input to remove any special character from a string. removeSpecialChars variable gets user input through ajax.

Comment: How do you create `engine`?

Comment: Added script engine in question.

Comment: Why do you need to script this? If the raw values come why can't you just use those as--all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");
removeSpecialChars = ".replace('a','')";
text = "Dia";
engine.put("first", text);
result = engine.eval("first" + removeSpecialChars);
System.out.println(result);
```

By calling `engine.put("first", text);` you create a variable `first` with the String `Dia.replace('a','')` as value. Evaluating this variable is simply a noop, that's why you get the same value as result again.

You can furthermore shorten the above to

```
result = engine.eval("\"" + text + "\"" + removeSpecialChars);
```

Try it out on glot.io: https://glot.io/snippets/f4jyrbt92h

You should however probably be very careful with what operations you allow and need to make sure malicious user input will not screw your whole system. If for example the user input is `.replace('a',''); file("C:/Windows/").delete();` this might be something you don't want to execute. In general accepting user input for dynamic code execution makes your system an easy target for all kind of exploits.

Comment: Thanks buddy! 
It was very much informational,  I will make sure to add security layer for user inputs.